# How to get tooltip on the hover of the label in material ui slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, slider

I am trying to create a slider quiz and what i want is on the hover of the label on the slider the tooltip appears

Right now when i hover on the thumb and its on the location of my mouse i can see the tooltip
Here is the image

The mouse is denoted my red M
[image]

I want to show the tooltip when the mouse is on other value
[image]

And when the thumb and mouse is on the same point the toolpoint is visible
[image]

Here is the code on how I am using this

```
<PrettoSlider1     
      ValueLabelComponent={ValueLabelComponent2}
/>
```

```
 const ValueLabelComponent2 = (props) => {
    const { children, value } = props;
    if (value === 0) {
      return (
        <Tooltip placement="top" title={"Strongly disagree"}>
          {children}
        </Tooltip>
      );
    } else if (value <= 1) {
      return (
        <Tooltip placement="top" title={"Disagree"}>
          {children}
        </Tooltip>
      );
    } else if (value <= 2) {
      return (
        <Tooltip placement="top" title={"Neutral"}>
          {children}
        </Tooltip>
      );
    } else if (value <= 3) {
      return (
        <Tooltip placement="top" title={"Agree"}>
          {children}
        </Tooltip>
      );
    } else if (value <= 4) {
      return (
        <Tooltip placement="top" title={"Strongly agree"}>
          {children}
        </Tooltip>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Tooltip placement="top" title={""}>
          {children}
        </Tooltip>
      );
    }
  };
```

Is it possible that if i hover like in 2nd image I can get the tooltip without the presence of thumb

Comment: Let me know if you wanna know more about this will try to explain at explicit as i can

Comment: Same issue here. Have you figured it out?

Comment: Unfortunately no